# How to insert to database in bulk instead of inserting it 1 by 1

Tags: c#, linq

How do you make the `list` receives more than 1 value based on the quantity of the `SelectedList.Count`.

Code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < SelectedList.Count; i++)
            {
                lastSeriesNo++;

                string assetcodegen = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", List[i].AssetCategoryID, CurrentApplication.Now.Year, lastSeriesNo.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0'));
                AssetCodeOfficial[i] = assetcodegen;


                var list = (from x in ctx.DataContext.AssetRegistryEntities
                            where x.AssetCode == SelectedList[i].AssetCode
                            select x
                            ).AsEnumerable();

                foreach (var asset in list)
                {
                    asset.SeriesNumber = (short)lastSeriesNo;
                    asset.Status = 'A';
                    asset.IsTemp = false;
                    asset.UpdatedBy = CurrentApplication.CurrentUserId;
                    asset.UpdatedDate = asset.AssetCreatedDate = CurrentApplication.Now;
                    AssetCodetemp[i] = asset.AssetCode;
                    depreciationInMonths = asset.DepnInMonths;

                    ctx.DataContext.SubmitChanges();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Assign to local variable `var currentCode = SelectedList[I].AssetCode` and use `currentCode` in LINQ query..

Comment: Also consider to rewrite this query to load and save everything in one batch.

Comment: what do you meant by "receive more than 1 value"? also, what type is `x.AssetCode`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv you mean I will create a variable within the for loop ? I tried your suggestion but still the same, receives only 1 value.

Comment: @BagusTesa, So I have a `List<something>` which is called `list` variable. My problem is in that current query it only receives 1 value instead of receiving based on the quantity of `SelectedList.Count`. `x.AssetCode` is a string datatype

Comment: Your `list` variable is declared inside your loop, maybe you want to declare it outside of it, and use `.Add` or `.AddRange` if you want to fill this list while you iterate through `SelectedList`

Comment: @Rafalon,okay I got your point but how do you use `.Add` since `list.AddRange(SelectedList[i]);` gives me error since they are not the same class object the `list` and `SelectedList`

Comment: hi, could you rephrase your question on what you actually wanted to achieve? is it to bulk insert the `SelectedList` into a table or something? we can't help if you didnt help us to understand the question.

Comment: @Its_Me I mean maybe instead of `var list = {1}` you should use `list.AddRange({1})` (where `{1}` is the linq code you wrote)

Comment: @BagusTesa,sorry for that, I already change the question.

Comment: hi, uh.. changing the title didnt help much. you see, there are at least 2 variables that have questionable use (e.g. `AssetCodeOfficial`, `AssetCodeTemp`). maybe a tour to [mcve] will help? for now, i could only give you clues how to fetch the `list` based on `SelectedList` in one query (it uses lambda): `ctx.DataContext.AssetRegistryEntities.Where(x => SelectedList.Any(y => y.AssetCode == x.AssetCode)).AsEnumerable()`. though, i doubt this will be useful as you have `assetcodegen` which dependent on the for loop.

Comment: @all Thank you guys for the help. I manage to solve it using `.AddRange`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all guys for the help, I manage to fix my problem. It already saves the data to the database as bulk not 1 by 1 saving.

So I use lambda expression for my `list` and use the `.addRange` to add item to the list.
`list.AddRange(ctx.DataContext.AssetRegistryEntities.Where(x=>x.AssetCode.Trim() == SelectedList[i].AssetCode.Trim()));`

```
Code:

List<NXpert.FixedAsset.DataAccess.AssetRegistryEntity> list = new List<NXpert.FixedAsset.DataAccess.AssetRegistryEntity>();

                for (int i = 0; i < SelectedList.Count; i++)
                {
                    lastSeriesNo++;

                    string assetcodegen = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", List[i].AssetCategoryID, CurrentApplication.Now.Year, lastSeriesNo.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0'));
                    AssetCodeOfficial[i] = assetcodegen;

                    list.AddRange(ctx.DataContext.AssetRegistryEntities.Where(x=>x.AssetCode.Trim() == SelectedList[i].AssetCode.Trim()));
                    AssetCodetemp[i] = list[i].AssetCode;
                }

                foreach (var asset in list)
                {
                    asset.SeriesNumber = (short)lastSeriesNo;
                    asset.Status = 'A';
                    asset.IsTemp = false;
                    asset.UpdatedBy = CurrentApplication.CurrentUserId;
                    asset.UpdatedDate = asset.AssetCreatedDate = CurrentApplication.Now;
                    depreciationInMonths = asset.DepnInMonths;
                }
                ctx.DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```